# Date values between two times for each day of the month

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a task where I need to extract data from an API. I need to specify to only collect data between 7am and 9pm for every day in a given month.

This will be a Bash script that will run at 00:01 on the 1st of each month using cron.

The API will only accept times in Epoch time. The script needs to be flexible enough so I don't have to code in every single day of a year.

I am having problems wrapping my head around this issue. I can get the first day of a month with the epoch time at 7am and the epoch time at 9pm, the API will accept these two epoch values and looks between the 2 times.

I can also get last day of the month with the epoch time at 7am and again at 9pm.

What I cannot figure out are the days between the first and last day of the month for 7am epoch and 9pm epoch.

```
START_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-01" -d "-1 Month");
START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$START_LAST_MONTH 7am");
START_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$START_LAST_MONTH 9pm");


END_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$START_LAST_MONTH +1 month -1 day");
END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$END_LAST_MONTH 7am");
END_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$END_LAST_MONTH 9pm");
```

I am thinking a way to achieve this is to add a 86400 seconds to the 7am and 9pm START_DAY variables, creating new variables by doing so, then increment upwards a day until the END_DAY 7am and 9pm Epoch time variables are hit. This should be flexible then for each month, since the number of days in a month vary.

But this is beyond my bash scripting skills and I am looking to learn how to achieve this so any help would be appreciated, another angle to look at this from is also fine.

UPDATE:

I now have this in a bash script

```
#!/bin/sh -x

START_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-01" -d "-1 Month");
START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$START_LAST_MONTH 7am");
START_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$START_LAST_MONTH 9pm");


END_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$START_LAST_MONTH +1 month -1 day");
END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$END_LAST_MONTH 7am");
END_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$END_LAST_MONTH 9pm");

until [ $END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE ]
do
let ADD_ONE_DAY=$START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE+86400
echo $ADD_ONE_DAY
done
```

But its not echoing the ADD_ONE_DAY variable at all. When debugging using -X it gets to here: until [ $END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE ] and doesnt do anything further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your updated example code is that in the loop condition you are effectively only checking `$END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE` not to be empty - which is just set two lines above, therefore the loop body is never executed.

To make your example work as intended try these modifications:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x

START_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-01" -d "-1 Month");
START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$START_LAST_MONTH 7am");
START_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$START_LAST_MONTH 9pm");


END_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$START_LAST_MONTH +1 month -1 day");
END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$END_LAST_MONTH 7am");
END_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH_DATE=$(date +%s -d"$END_LAST_MONTH 9pm");

ADD_ONE_DAY=$START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE
until [ "$ADD_ONE_DAY" -gt "$END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE" ]
do
let ADD_ONE_DAY=$ADD_ONE_DAY+86400
echo $ADD_ONE_DAY
done
```

1. adjust the loop condition to test whether `$ADD_ONE_DAY` is greater than `$END_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE`
2. initialize `$ADD_ONE_DAY` with before the loop `$START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE`
3. within the loop increment `$ADD_ONE_DAY` by one day (instead of `$START_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH_DATE`, which results in always the same value, i.e. an endless loop)

---

Another solution in order to loop through all days of a month using the `seq` command could be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

START_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-01" -d "-1 Month")
END_LAST_MONTH=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$START_LAST_MONTH +1 month -1 day")

CURRENT_YEAR=$(date +%Y -d "-1 Month")
CURRENT_MONTH=$(date +%m -d "-1 Month")
LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH=$(date +%d -d "$END_LAST_MONTH");

for CURRENT_DAY in $(seq -w 1 "$LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH"); do
    CURRENT_DATE="$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DAY"
    CURRENT_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH=$(date +%s -d"$CURRENT_DATE 7am")
    CURRENT_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH=$(date +%s -d"$CURRENT_DATE 9pm")

    echo "$CURRENT_DAY_SEVEN_AM_EPOCH - $CURRENT_DAY_NINE_PM_EPOCH"
done
```

Here `seq -w 1 "$LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH"` will generate a sequence from 1 to the last day of the respective month, the `-w` outputs the numbers with *equal width* filling in 0s if necessary, i.e. "01", "02", ...

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response, I will try this. Great post

Comment: Perfect your second code works perfectly well and exactly how I would like it formatted. I am learning from this so thank you

Comment: Could I ask why you named the variables in this way for your second section of code. Because ```CURRENT_MONTH=$(date +%m -d "-1 Month")``` this is throwing me off slightly. Where it is referred to as current month but you still minus the 1 month. I guess its just an arbitrary label for the variable and nothing more because I do understand what this code is doing after learning more about seq command

Comment: Yeah, the naming was maybe a bit arbitrary (=
I named it `CURRENT_MONTH` to be used in `CURRENT_DATE` to be read as _date currently processed in this loop iteration_. So the naming is indeed not necessarily perfect.